# Regex don't work as expected in nginx map

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

I'm trying to achieve some URL rewrite rules in nginx. I use similar regex to capture the interesting groups, it works perfectly in regex101, and in IIS rewrite rules' regex, but not working in nginx map. I don't know exactly if there is a specific syntax for nginx or not, I couldn't find out.

```
  map $request_uri $new_uri {        
      default '';
      
      # this works without the query string part
      #"~^/r/([\S]+)\.jpg$" http://www.jackli.space/$1.jpg;

      "~^/r/([\S]+).(png|jpg|jpeg)\?a=(\d+)$" http://www.jackli.space/$1.$2?x=$3;
  }
```

Sample image src url I test with

```
<img src="r/images/bridge.jpg?a=100" />
```

[image: Regex 101 for same expression]

Comment: Can you show rewrite rule you are trying to use?

Comment: here is the sample conf file for nginx

```map $request_uri $new_uri {
      default '';      
      "~^/r/([\S]+).(png|jpg|jpeg)\?a=(\d+)$" http://www.jackli.space/$1.$2?x=$3;
  }

  server {
    listen 4000;
    location / {
      if ($new_uri) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $new_uri permanent;
      }
      proxy_pass http://backend:5000;
    }
  }```

Comment: Try `return 301 $new_uri;` instead of `rewrite` directive. And you'd better add that configuration fragment to your question, markdown formatting in comments isn't suited well for multiline code blocks.

Comment: @IvanShatsky, I tried this, it is not working. the reason I didn't put the configuration in the question because it is irrelevant, the problem is in the regex not in the configuration.

Comment: I don't see any errors in your regex. Tested this on my local machine, everything is working as expected (see used nginx config and curl log [here](https://pastebin.com/2Et43daE)).

Comment: An important update. As you can see in my example, the `Location` header content with the given config is `http://localhost/some/path/image.jpg?x=100?a=100`. Use `rewrite ^ $new_uri? permanent;` or `return 301 $new_uri;` to get correct `http://localhost/some/path/image.jpg?x=100` header value.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this block with named captured groups:

```sh
map $request_uri $new_uri {        
   default 0;
      
   # this works without the query string part
   #"~^/r/([\S]+)\.jpg$" http://www.jackli.space/$1.jpg;

   "~^/r/(?<file>\S+)\.(?<ext>png|jpg|jpe?g)\?a=((?<a>\d+)$" http://www.jackli.space/$file.$ext?x=$a;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. However I found a bug in the regex groups I used (fixed in the question), yet still it is not working.

Comment: What is full URL you're using to test this?

Comment: it's http://localhost:4000/r/images/bridge.jpg?a=100